# When connecting to a project in TFS block local repo

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, How do you connect to a TFVC project in TFS and prevent it from creating a local repo?  I want to be able to copy files from another project in VS 2017 and check-in but not have all the files from that project local?

Answer (score 0):

In the source control explorer, drill down to the project folder you want to add the files to, right click on the folder (you don't have to have it checked out) and click "Add items to Folder".

You should see an "Add to source control" dialog that is showing files from your local computer. From there, it's not too hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to a TFVC project in TFS you could select to create local workspace or not. But we could not restrict users to create local repo or not.

If you do not want others to pull files from server to local, you need to use **[permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/security/permissions?view=vsts)** to do the restriction.

You could directly copy files from another project to your local workspace, VS will auto detect changes and list in the pending change list. You just need to check in files.

More ways about how to add files to the server, please review this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=vsts).